# How to Align Vertically the image in a div?

Tags: css, html, image

How to display the image as vertical align in div container?

The image "setting.png" placed in last column in the code i attached. please advice solution please.

```
.table{
width: 100%;
margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.tableRow{
width: 100%;
clear: both;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.tableCol{
float: left;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
}

<div class="table">
    <div class="tableRow">
        <div class="tableCol" style="width:10%; text-align:center;">1</div>
        <div class="tableCol" style="width:40%">Michael</div>
        <div class="tableCol" style="width:40%">webexp@gmail.com</div>
        <div class="tableCol" style="width:10%;">
        <a href="" ><img src="images/icons/setting.png" alt="Setting" align="absmiddle"  /></a>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `&nbsp;` (space before a link)

```
  <div class="table">
        <div class="tableRow">
            <div class="tableCol" style="width:10%; text-align:center;">1</div>
            <div class="tableCol" style="width:40%">Michael</div>
            <div class="tableCol" style="width:40%">webexp@gmail.com</div>
            <div class="tableCol" style="width:10%;">&nbsp;
            <a href="" ><img src="images/icons/setting.png" alt="Setting" align="absmiddle"  /></a>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

better solution:
add this to css:

```
img {
margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: better solution would be add to css: img {
margin-top:10px;
}

Comment: ok thanks, but its not proper way right because in some cases the tableCol height be increase then we have increase margin-top also right? is there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Here, this should work:
Add this to your div which contains the image that should be centered.

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

This should center the image vertically no matter the dimensions of your div or the image that it contains.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with **position: absolute;** if you know the dimensions of the settings.png image (20px x 20px for this example).

Add class **tableColSettings** to the `<a>` around the settings image. Then add CSS;

```
.tableColSettings{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -10px 0 0 -10px; /* Half image dimensions */
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 0;
}
.tableColSettings img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

The settings image will always stay in the center of the element, no matter the height. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/384pa/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

Css is having a tag name
 "vertical-align" may be you will get your solution

Comment: `vertical-align` is a CSS *property*, not a "tag name".

Comment: i have mention already in css .. you can google and search css tag then you will find css tag is css property. so dont try to be over smart @PavloMykhalov

Comment: I meant no disrespect, just want to help. It's a matter of definion, and the correct definition is, with no doubt, a "property". If you still unsure, I suggest you to explore [CSS basics @ WebEd](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS_basics#What_is_CSS.3F), [Declarations, Properties, and Values @ SitePoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/declarations), [CSS Syntax @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Syntax).

Comment: I've alrady saw it — it's ridiculously incorrect, that's why you won't find another source which defines it in the same way. Consider the reputation of the source you are refering to: MDN and Web Education Community Group Wiki is created by companies and people who are at the head of modern web development.